# find/get specific strings between strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Suppose, I have string like this

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b], sed eiusmod tempor [i]incidunt ut labore[/i] et [size =12]dolore [/size=12] magna aliqua"
```

I would like to get like this Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **consectetur adipisici elit**, sed eiusmod tempor *incidunt ut labore* et `dolore` magna aliqua". But this is not my question.

Question: how do i get strings between `[b]...[\b]`  and `[i] ..[/i]` or string between `[size=12].. [/size=12]` in textarea, when i append to div? text between [b][/b] should become **bold**, between `[i][/i]` should become *italic* and text between `[size][/size]` should be font size...

Comment: use indexOf to find where the [b] and the [/b] are.  Then you can can a substring between those two...

Comment: an example would not hurt me

Comment: There are a thousand questions about bbcodes, search the site.

Comment: But the question is how do i find it in textarea when i append this text to a div.

Comment: That's not in the question anywhere.  If that's what you want, then you need to make the question **clear**.

Comment: And do you NEED the strings between the tags? Or could you just **replace** the tags with bold / italic tags? `str.replace('[b]', '<b>')`, for example?

Comment: thats good idea.. too. I tired but does not workingg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separated pattern:

To get everything between `[b]` and `[\b]`:

```
\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]
```

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b], sed eiusmod tempor [i]incidunt ut labore[/i] et dolore magna aliqua";
var result = /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/.exec(str);
document.write(result[1]);
```

---

To get everything between `[i]` and `[/i]`:

```
\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]
```

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b], sed eiusmod tempor [i]incidunt ut labore[/i] et dolore magna aliqua";
var result = /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/.exec(str);
document.write(result[1]);
```

---

Also if you need to replace the content, try this:

```js
    var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b], sed eiusmod tempor [i]incidunt ut labore[/i] et dolore magna aliqua";
    var result = str.replace(/\[b\]|\[\/b\]/g,'**').replace(/\[i\]|\[\/i\]/g,'*');
    document.write(result);
```

Comment: something i want like this but there is one more problem... that is about size  pattern. how do i get pattern of size

Comment: @hijckBoy Do you mean something like this? [`/\[size(:?.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size(:?.*?)\]/`](https://regex101.com/r/xX5sQ1/2)

Comment: yes ty. how did u learn this pattern  ? ** or *  astriks are used in markdown  language. i dont think is it possible to use also in markup. I would vote up you but i cant sorry.

Comment: There is a lot of resources which are containing great tutorials. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is my suggestion.